# Update script if element class changes

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have a problem. I was finding solution on many formus, but I didn't find it.

I have a **div** with **class="first"** and I have this script:

```
$(".first").click(function() {
  alert("HI");
});
```

Then I have a **button** and script to change class of div above:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".first").attr( "class", "second" );
});
```

And another script for **div** with **class="second"**:

```
$(".second").click(function() {
  alert("GOODBYE");
});
```

*And the problem:*
If I click on **div**, when it has **class first**, it outputs **"HI"**.
Then I click on **button**.
Then I click on **div**, when it has **class second**, it outputs **"HI"** (like in the first case). But I want, it outputs **"GOODBYE"**.

Can you help me with this, please?
*Sorry for my english, but it isn't my first language.*

Comment: You are just adding a new class to the element and not removing the old one. Inspect your HTML with some developer tools (Chrome or FireFox)

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the initial class from your element. Try using a generic `div` selector and using `toggleClass`. This checks if an element has a class, and adds/removes it accordingly.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").toggleClass("second");
    $("div").toggleClass("first");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r8ybd6bg/

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)